# Is there a way to make a style tag in a component have very low priority?

Tags: reactjs

I am making a component and its style has to be easily overridable but since I have to set some default styling programmatically this is proving difficult.

Is there a way to set a style tag in a component and make it load in the head of the HTML document before any other style tags so that it is overridden by anything else comes after?

I am new to react so it is very possible that I am missing something obvious

What I have:

```
<div>
   <div style={{someStyle: var, ...props.style}}/>
</div>
```

What I want:

```
<div>
   <SpecialSauceComponentThatLoadsStyleInHead>
      <style>
          .low-priority-scoped-class{
              someStyle: programmaticallySetStyling;
          }
      </style>
   </SpecialSauceComponentThatLoadsStyleInHead>
   <div className={["low-priority-scoped-class", props.className].join(" ")}/>
</div>
```

so that I can do this

```
<ProgrammaticallySetToRedComponent className="nowItIsBlue" />
```

Instead of this

```
<ProgrammaticallySetToRedComponent style={{background: "blue"}} />
```

Comment: please provide code and show us what your tried

Comment: It was a very general question about best practices and the way of doing things in React so I didn't think code samples would be needed but here you go!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is either CSS modules or a CSS-in-JS solution like styled-components. There are many approaches out there, all with their own pros/cons

Comment: Is there a way to guarantee that the styled-component style gets overridden by literally any other styling? What I am looking for is not specifically CSS-in-JS but easily overridable styling. I want a component that I am making to have a bare bone default style  but still have it feel like a native HTML element where whatever styling you apply to it in whatever way you like will always override it's original styling.

Comment: The only way I can think of doing it is to somehow guarantee style tags order in the head of the page. I also looked into react helmet but that also doesn't guarantee the order of the content it adds to the head of the page.

Comment: You can provide a stylesheet for your component(s), the user of those components can import those styles and as long as they import their own styles underneath then they will be able to override the styles.